# Jquery not working in mobile view in data tables responsive

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, laravel-5.3, bootstrap-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IResd.png)Jquery not working in mobile view when data table responsive.
it is working properly in desktop.

here is my code

```
<table class="table steps-table data-table mt-2 table-bordered-none" width="100%"><thead class="thead-default">
                <tr class="hidden-xs-down">
                    <th>SHARE LINK</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach($goals as $goal)
                    <tr>
             <td><i class="fa fa-facebook bg-blue white h-2 w-2 lh-2 text-center round cursor-pointer fb-share" data-share-url="{{ $goal->generateLink() }}"></i></td></tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
```

Here is my data table code

```
$('.data-table').DataTable({
    'lengthChange': false,
    'searching': false,
    'responsive': true,
    'order': [[0, 'desc']],
    'responsive': true,
    'pagingType': 'simple',
    'language': {
        'info': '_START_&ndash;_END_ of _TOTAL_ <div class="text-muted text-sm">All times are US Eastern.</span>',
        'emptyTable': 'Nothing here yet.'
    }
});
```

Comment: Please define "*not working*" ....

Comment: Hi @davidkonrad where should i keep 'not working'

Comment: hey @Juluri, just meant: What exactly is not working? Is the dataTable never initialised or is it the responsive part that is not being responsive...?

Comment: Hi @davidkonrad,ya when i opened site in mobile devices or when i'm testing in browser the inside the data table jquery functionality is not working.Here a popup need to open when i click on <i class="fa fa-facebook bg-blue white h-2 w-2 lh-2 text-center round cursor-pointer fb-share" data-share-url="{{ $goal->generateLink() }}"></i>

Comment: it works fine in desktop.

Comment: I have added image link on top the data table looks like that

Comment: OK, Then there is only guesses left ... Hard to see what can be done here without an example that reproduces the behaviour.  Try take it to the datatables forum.

Comment: okay @davidkonrad, thank you.